# Encapsulate a method that start an activity, outside an activity

Tags: android, authentication, android-intent, google-authentication

I am trying to create a method that authentificates a Google user on Firebase.

I am using this method in 3 different activities, and I would like to clean up the code making a method.

This is the code im trying to make as a static method in a class.

```
  private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct, final Context activity, FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        Log.d("MainACtivity", "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());

        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(activity, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d("Main", "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w("MainAcitivyt", "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(activity, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else{
                            startActivity(AccountCreationActivity.newIntent(activity));
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

I am having problems to understand how I can use the 'startActivity' from another class when called on my methods. 
Or second choice I also have been trying is to return a intent, but since 'onComplete' returns void im totally lost how to proceed.

Here is the code for my Google sign-up/login that I would like to copy in different activities and was planning to create a method of it in another class. I think the only method I cant take out from my sign-up Activity is the 'onACtivityResult'

```
private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            try {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                Log.w(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e);
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
        Log.d("MainACtivity", "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());

        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d("Main", "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                        // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                        // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                        // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w("MainAcitivyt", "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else{
                            startActivity(AccountCreationActivity.newIntent(getActivity()));
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how I can use the 'startActivity' from another class

Use instance of `Context` to start activity. You have `Context activity` in method parameters, use it.

```
private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct, final Context activity, FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        Log.d("MainACtivity", "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());

        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
        firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(activity, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Log.d("Main", "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.w("MainAcitivyt", "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                            Toast.makeText(activity, "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else{
                           // This line has been changed.
                           activity.startActivity(AccountCreationActivity.newIntent(activity));
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```